# Minimum set of vertices that allow reaching all other vertices in max. one edge

Tags: graph, minimum, vertices

this is probably a stupid question, but what is the canonical problem that asks for the minimum set of vertices out of a graph, so that from these vertices, all other vertices can be reached by "traveling" no more than one edge?
The real-life application would be: Which people do I need to know, to be connected to everybody else on the planet by just one degree?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's the [Dominating Set Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set), closely related to the normal set cover problem